# How to Boot Xubuntu 16.04 from UEFI Firmware

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu

I recently decided to attempt to install Xubuntu 16.04 over my previous Windows 10 OS that shipped on my Acer Aspire E15 laptop with UEFI firmware. After creating an install media on a flash drive, I followed the procedure to completely erase the Windows OS and install Xubuntu on the drive in it's place. However, on restart it shows no bootable device. How can I get the bootloader registered with the firmware?

Some settings in the InsydeH20 Setup Utility that might be relevant:
- Boot Mode: UEFI
- Secure Boot: Disabled
- Supervisor Password Is: Set
- Secure Boot Mode: Standard (a number of greyed out options underneath here; erasing secure boot settings, selecting trusted UEFI files, factory restore to secure boot settings)

Note I am not trying to keep the Windows 10 OS for dual boot, it is gone already. Is there a way I can circumvent whatever issues the UEFI firmware introduces directly?

Comment: Search here for "Acer Aspire E15" and if memory serves me, there's a file copy/move that you have to do, or something in the BIOS, to get this to boot properly.

Comment: Is it a Signature Edition machine?

Comment: Try disabling Secure Boot and adding a password to the UEFI (Supervisor).

Comment: It is not a Signature Edition machine and I noted that Secure Boot has already been disabled and a supervisor password set.

Comment: @heynnema Searched and found a set of directions that managed to work for me, thank you! Problem was that I wasn't able to set the UEFI file to load to Grub as the option was greyed out. I believe it was because I needed to Enable Secure Boot mode and then reboot again to see these options made available.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to finally get the Boot options available and was able to follow these directions going forward: [Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot)